# How to convert mxnet.ndarray.ndarray.NDArray to a scalar?

Tags: python, mxnet

I got a weird object that shows like this...

```
type(l.sum())
l.sum()
```

This is what it outputs:

```
<class 'mxnet.ndarray.ndarray.NDArray'>
[83.32651]
<NDArray 1 @cpu(0)>
```

I want to convert it to a scalar but no matter how I try it stays as array.

```
l.sum()[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
```

Still outputs:

```
[83.32651]
<NDArray 1 @cpu(0)>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some unknown reasons probably the misbehavior is caused by **sum()**.

Converting to numpy before the operation has solved the problem:

```
l.asnumpy().sum()
```

This returns a scalar as expected.